# Tomcat can´t access network drives on Windows

Tags: windows, tomcat, service, resources, windows-server-2012

I have `Tomcat 8` installed as service on `Windows server 2012`. The problem is that **Tomcat can´t access network drives**. The tomcat manager shows that it is logged on as `Local System Account`. I've changed that to `This account` and selected the current user which i use to get logged in on Windows, but when i put its password and press apply , the password is automatically changed to another one and Tomcat can not start its service.
Can you tell me how to configure Tomcat so that it could be able to access network drives?

Comment: Where and how are you changing the account/adding the password?

Comment: From Control Panel, Services, right click on Tomcat service, properties, Log On, This Account

Comment: The passwords in those fields are hidden. How can you tell that "the password is automatically changed to another one"?